# Block element seems to ignore height property

Tags: css

I display the `p` element as a block. But still it doesn't take the `height` value I apply. Why? :/

```css
p {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec mattis urna. Proin dictum mattis ex quis convallis. Integer ac enim dolor. Maecenas erat nisi, volutpat ut erat sit amet, consectetur sodales leo. Donec convallis leo ut sodales gravida. Vestibulum et sem mi. Quisque ut fringilla augue. Suspendisse in purus mollis, vestibulum tellus quis, volutpat lectus. Quisque vel vehicula lectus. Aenean tristique in nisi at sagittis. Nam non vehicula nunc.orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec mattis urna. Proin dictum mattis ex quis convallis. Integer ac enim dolor. Maecenas erat nisi, volutpat ut erat sit amet, consectetur sodales leo. Donec convallis leo ut sodales gravida. Vestibulum et sem mi. Quisque ut fringilla augue. Suspendisse in purus mollis, vestibulum tellus quis, volutpat lectus. Quisque vel vehicula lectus. Aenean tristique in nisi at sagittis. Nam non vehicula nunc.</p>
```

Comment: Sorry will add now.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with the `width`, so I removed that mention. And have have transformed your code blocks to a runnable code snippet, this way there is no need of linking a third-party image.

Answer (score 1):

The width and height are definitely correct. The problem is called *overflowing content*. The text *overflows* the elements boundaries, and that [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) is visible, by default. You can change that to the behaviour that you want. What you want is probably to show a scrollbar. For that you need `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll`. If you just want to cut off the overflow, use `overflow: hidden`. I have given an example of the most frequent values for `overflow` below.

```css
p {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.scroll p {
  overflow: scroll;
}
.auto p {
  overflow: auto;
}
.hidden p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll">
  <h1>Always show scrollbar. <code>overflow: scroll</code></h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.
    Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean
    quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum.
    Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis,
    tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit.
    Sed lectus.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.</p>
</section>
<section class="auto">
  <h1>Shows scrollbar when necessary. <code>overflow: auto</code></h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.
    Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean
    quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum.
    Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis,
    tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit.
    Sed lectus.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.</p>
</section>
<section class="hidden">
  <h1>Clipped. <code>overflow: hidden</code></h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.
    Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean
    quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum.
    Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis,
    tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit.
    Sed lectus.</p>
  </section
```

Answer (score 0):

The `p` element is `block` by default. Since the amount of text in that element exceeds the dimensions that you set, they actually `overflow`.

If you want to completely hide anything that pushes beyond the dimensions, you can set `overflow: hidden`. Or, if you want to simulate scroll, set `overflow: scroll`.

Add more information about what you're trying to do, if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thank's alot, no i was not looking for scroll bar was just wondering why it exceeds dimensions ! Don't know why soo much hate on my question..

Comment: @ParasKaushal Because this is one of the most basic of basic questions, but you get more down-votes because if you would just have googled the issue you would have found dozens of answers. And finally, because you didn't provide any HTML. Always provide a reproducible example that we can start working with, so that we don't have to guess what your code could be.

Comment: I google it but english was not good i din't get any answers.